# implementing password rules in grails

Tags: grails, passwords, policy

I want to implement password rules to be of minimum length 8 and alphanumeric. The new and confirm fields are getting checked now, These rules should be applied when creating a new instance of a user and change password functionality for the existing user also.
1) If there is a grails plugin which can do this.
2) is having javascript based validation a good strategy , if not how can I do it manually without a plugin.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use a http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Constraints/validator.html in the constraint for the password.

Comment: Thanks but we are using grails 1.3.7 version, not yet migrated to grails 2.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

What Ray has suggested should work because what he is referring to is custom validations and this is part of 1.3.7 as well. (Its is just he is referring to the docs of 2.0) You just need to to write down all the rules in the custom validation and before your object is persisted to the database it will be validated against all those rules or you can invoke the validate() method on object any time to validate the values before saving.

Coming to second part of your question : Should you have javascript checks for the same.

Answer is Yes. It is always good to have both client side and server side validations in place  as client side validations will make sure that user experience is better and server side validations will maintain the integrity of your data. Though client side validation will also ensure the integrity but since those can be by passed, so you should not rely on those only.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of doing this. @ray-tayek assumed the password is stored as a Domain class field, but that wouldn't be sufficiently private: the password would be sent over the network (be it an intranet or the internet) as plain text, and would be saved to the database in the same fashion. However, the former is not true if you're using HTTPS, so (instead of using a custom validator) you can use the `matches` constrains which takes a regular expression (untested):

```
class User {
    String username
    String password

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false // whatever
        password minLenght: 8, matches: /^[\d\p{L}]*$/  // Digits or any kind of letter
    }
}
```

Anyway, what I would do is validate the password client side with JavaScript, when it's correct compute a hash such as [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) and send it to the server. In that case, all you need to check server-side is that the hash conforms to a SHA-1 string, which can be easily done:

```
    static constraints = {
        // ...
        passwordHash matches: /^\b[0-9a-f]{5,40}\b$/
    }
```

So, when the user tries to log in you should check the stored and sent hashes against each other, instead of using plain passwords.